# VS2017 SSIS Parallel Processing error (?)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parallel-processing

I am trying to run parallel processes to read Excel Files into an OLEDB Destination. However on runtime, SSIS doesn't show errors though it simply stops and states:

"Package Execution completed. Click here to switch to design mode, or select Stop Debugging from the Debug Menu".

No rows have been inserted with the parallel processes and I can't find the root cause of this 'completion' in the messages list. I've provided a screenshot as an example:

[image: SSIS runtime 'completion error']

The MaxConcurrentExecutables is set to 5, the Run64Bit property is set to True (False didn't change anything), and the EngineThreads property is set to 1.

Could anyone help on this problem?

Comment: What is happening if the Data Flow tasks are executed sequentially ?

Comment: And you are sure your tables are empty? Sometimes its a visual bug, and it has actually inserted data.

Comment: @holder: If the Data Flow task would be executed sequentially it would run without problems. However the loop will have to go through at least 8000 files for a full load. Parallel processing could reduce the total time to a maximum of 50%

Comment: @Thomas Unfortunately it's not a visual bug. I checked the tables in SQL Server but those tables are empty.

Comment: @MarcVandewall  Allright, I missed the For Loop. Maybe you are missing some mapping of variables which the for loop is iterating over? Please add some more information / pictures of what the Data Flows within the Test container is doing.

Comment: @holder The Foreach Loop is iterating over a Folder which contains Excel files. These Excel sources contain two sheets. Let's call them Foo and Bar. In the Data Flow Task the following happens:

DFT 1: Import Sheet Foo --> DC Change types --> Export to Staging Table: Staging_Foo

DFT 2: Import Sheet Bar --> DC Change types --> Export to Staging Table: Staging_Bar.

However I have to note that BOTH Data Flow tasks read from the SAME source file but export to DIFFERENT staging tables.

Comment: @MarcVandewall It might have to do with performance issues / timeout. How's the memory usage on the machine while running? 
Have you tried to deploy it to your SSIS server and run it there?

Comment: @holder Unfortunately I can't deploy it to an SSIS server, because my colleagues only run one server at the moment of which the production- AND development data is processed. They don't want to give me access to this server.

I can check locally, but I don't think it should give this much issues tbh. The specs are:
Windows 10 Enterprise
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1505M 2.81Ghz
RAM: 32GB
System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: @MarcVandewall Ok..I would try to load less files to see if i makes any difference.

Comment: The Test Container seems still to be running - how long did you wait before going back to Design Mode? I had a similar problem in the past, where the process was not finished but VS stated it was.

Comment: @MarcVandewall Can you please post a picture of the twin data flows and the foreach loop editor?

Comment: @MarcVandewall Two questions. 1.) if you disable one of the data flows, will the job load data? 2.) In either of the data flows, are you retrieving data from the same table that the file is being loaded to (i.e., comparing existing records to incoming records)? These both point to some type of blocking from either the file or the SQL Server. though, the latter would likely result in an error assuming your destination task is set to issue a table lock..

Comment: If you run your 2 DFT sequentially it runs? Have you tried to see your activity monitor on the sql-server when it runs paralell? Maybe some locks or something?

Comment: @Tyron78 I waited at least 15 mins, but still no data was loaded into the staging tables.

Comment: @JWeezy I tried to disable one of the tasks, and it works. I've posted my 'answer' below (which shows somewhat of an explanation of what is happening). So yes, this comment probably is the answer, because I think that the File (in this case Excel) is 'locked' to which no data could be retrieved.

Comment: @Thomas Yes the DFT Tasks run sequentially, that's how I use them now. I wanted to make them parallel so loading a bunch of Excel files would go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS cannot read the same file simultaneously. Yes, you are running into a locking issue.

The solution is to use one data connection and one data flow. In the data flow, read from the file, then add a multicast, which will allow you to duplicate the data flow as many times you want. From there, merge the tasks that are occurring in both data flows into one.

The net effect is that you will have one data flow; one data source; one multicast; two data pipelines where you can do some transformations; and two data destinations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is true, but I think I know the reason why it fails.

The reason why it suddenly 'stops' executing, could be due to the fact that once SSIS reads from an Excel File to import data, it 'locks' the Excel File. The second Data Flow Task open or access the file since it's already opened by Data Flow Task. See image below.[image: SSIS problem]

If someone could confirm this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See my answer for the solution to your problem.

Comment: OF cause you cannot read from the same file twice. If thats what your doing thats your error.Thats why i wanted you to check for locking errors. When you read a file like excel or CSV it opens it behind the scenes, and you cannot do this twice.

Comment: However my concerns is that you doenst state that in your question. Try to be a bit more clear next time. You only wrote that your were read excel files (multiple).

Comment: @Thomas My apologies. I'm a internship junior developer, who is a rookie in using stack overflow. Still in learning process :). Thanks for the help though!